# "日本語でOK"の広告はなくなった？

Tags: サポート, 広告

前に、"日本語でOK"という広告が本家SO(Stack Overflow)にありましたが、現在は見当たりません…

その広告は消えたのでしょうか？個人的には日本語SOに入ってきたきっかけがそれだったので(インパクトも凄い)、これも使ってもいいかなと思いました。

Comment: 勘違いのようですね…ありました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まだ表示されています。

見えない理由は3つの可能性があります：

1. AdBlock等で非表示されています
2. 信用度が高まると「広告を非表示にする」設定があります
3. 日本にいないなら、表示はされません

Comment: 見えないわけではなく、「別の広告しか表示されないな」と思っただけです。でも質問を何個か見てみるとありますね。